# Does the Klingon Empire use money?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

Last December, I saw *[A Klingon Christmas Carol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Klingon_Christmas_Carol)*, a parody play of Charles Dickens' *[A Christmas Carol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol)* set in a Klingon culture and performed almost entirely in the Klingon language (aside from a Vulcan narrator who speaks in English).

The main character is SQuja', who had the dishonorable job of being a moneylender instead of a warrior (at one point, someone taunts him saying he's no better than a Ferengi). Although it was secretly because of his cowardice, SQuja' said that he stuck to that profession because the Empire needed people like him in order to function and so he was just doing his duty.

In canon *Star Trek*, does the Klingon Empire use money? Or have they moved beyond that, like the Federation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Yes.** The best example I know of is that in Deep Space Nine's "The House of Quark", it's a major plot point that one house is scheming to take over another for their material wealth.

> QUARK: Very clever. Very clever indeed. D'Ghor has manipulated your family's holdings, devalued the lands you hold, and he is the principal creditor on Kozak's outstanding gambling debts. It's no accident your family's getting weaker and D'Ghor's family is getting stronger. He's been systematically attacking your family's assets for over five years now.
>   GRILKA: You mean D'Ghor has been scheming and plotting like a F?
>   QUARK: Like a Ferengi.
>   GRILKA: There is no honour in what he has done. If he wanted to challenge my House, he should've made a declaration, met our forces in battle.
>   QUARK: And risk destroying the very thing he wanted most, your lands and property?
>   GRILKA: Can you prove any of this? You can show the Council exactly what D'Ghor has done?
>   QUARK: It's all right there. All I have to do is talk them through it.

...

> QUARK: So, as you can see from the gross adjusted assets tabulation in column J, the net value of the land acquisition was actually zero. Now, if you go to the file marked Devaluation of Capital Income, we can review the way D'Ghor
>   GOWRON: Enough! I don't want to hear anything more about finances, mergers, or currency transactions. **The charge has been made that you have used money to bring down a great House.** What do you say to this, D'Ghor?

The latter quote in video form:

Comment: As for what they use as money, I don't recall any Klingon-specific currencies, although everyone uses latinum in DS9 so it's hard to tell if they do or don't.

Comment: Please link [this video](https://youtu.be/Q65l7RHUx2A). The block quote just does not do Gowron in that scene justice. =) +1

Comment: @jpmc26 If you insist =)

Answer (score 16):

According to Memory Alpha the Klingon currency is something called a [darsek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Darsek), this was also referred to in [TNG: Firstborn](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/273.txt)

> **ALEXANDER:** *There's a man over there who's got Molor's head in a box -- the real Molor.*
>
> **WORF:** *That is impossible. Molor died centuries ago.*
>
> **ALEXANDER:** *I know -- it's mummified. **He said he'd show it to us for fifty darseks.***

and in [Ent: Bounty](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/51.htm), where Archer is captured by a bounty hunter.

> **ARCHER:** *The Klingons took your freighter, your livelihood, damaged your relationship with your brother, and **what do you get in
>   exchange? Nine thousand darseks.** Doesn't seem like a very fair trade
>   to me.*

Comment: You might also want to mention that in the EU we also learn about two other Klingon currencies; The [Talon](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Talon_(currency)) and the [Deq](http://mughom.wikia.com/wiki/Conversational_Klingon/mu'tlheghmey) which roughly translates as a "Credit".